# Extracting a column with NA's from a bigmemory object in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, r-bigmemory

I'm trying to create a function that extracts a column from a big.matrix object in Rcpp (so that it can be analyzed in cpp before bringing the results to R), but I can't figure out how to get it to recognise NA's (they are now presented as -2147483648 - as shown in my minimal example below). It would be even better if I could access the function **GetMatrixCols** (*src/bigmemory.cpp*) straight from Rcpp, but I've yet to discover a way to do that.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH, bigmemory)]]
#include <bigmemory/MatrixAccessor.hpp>
#include <bigmemory/isna.hpp>
using namespace Rcpp;

//Logic for extracting column from a Big Matrix object
template <typename T>
NumericVector GetColumn_logic(XPtr<BigMatrix> pMat,  MatrixAccessor<T> mat,   int cn) {
  NumericVector nv(pMat->nrow());
  for(int i = 0; i < pMat->nrow(); i++) {
    if(isna(mat[cn][i])) {
      nv[i] = NA_INTEGER;
    } else {
      nv[i] = mat[cn][i];
    }
  }
  return nv;
}

//' Extract Column from a Big Matrix.
//' 
//' @param pBigMat A bigmemory object address.
//' @param colNum Column Number to extract. Indexing starts from zero.
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector GetColumn(SEXP pBigMat, int colNum) {
  XPtr<BigMatrix> xpMat(pBigMat);

  switch(xpMat->matrix_type()) {
    case 1: return GetColumn_logic(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<char>(*xpMat), colNum);
    case 2: return GetColumn_logic(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<short>(*xpMat), colNum);
    case 4: return GetColumn_logic(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<int>(*xpMat), colNum);
    case 6: return GetColumn_logic(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<float>(*xpMat), colNum);
    case 8: return GetColumn_logic(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<double>(*xpMat), colNum);
    default: throw Rcpp::exception("Unknown type detected for big.matrix object!");
  }
}

/*** R
bm <- bigmemory::as.big.matrix(as.matrix(reshape2::melt(matrix(c(1:4,NA,6:20),4,5))))
bigmemory:::CGetType(bm@address)
bigmemory:::GetCols.bm(bm, 3)
GetColumn(bm@address, 2)
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great one!  Stay with me for a moment:

*tl;dr*: It works once fixed:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/bigmemEx.cpp")

R> bm <- bigmemory::as.big.matrix(as.matrix(reshape2::melt(matrix(c(1:4,NA,6:20),4,5))))

R> bigmemory:::CGetType(bm@address)
[1] 4

R> bigmemory:::GetCols.bm(bm, 3)
 [1]  1  2  3  4 NA  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

R> GetColumn(bm@address, 2)
 [1]  1  2  3  4 NA  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
R>
```

The trouble starts at the inside.  When you create your matrix as

```
matrix(c(1:4,NA,6:20),4,5)
```

what do you get?  Integer!

```
R> matrix(c(1:4,NA,6:20),4,5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1   NA    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20
R> class(matrix(c(1:4,NA,6:20),4,5))
[1] "matrix"
R> typeof(matrix(c(1:4,NA,6:20),4,5))
[1] "integer"
R>
```

Not a problem *per se*, but a problem once you remember that the IEEE 754standard has NaN defined for floating point only (correct if I'm wrong).

The other issue is that you reflexively used `NumericVector` in your, but operate on integers.  Now R has `NaN`, and even `NA`, for floating point and integer, but 'normal libraries' outside of R do not.  And a bigmemory *by design* represents things outside of R, you're stuck.

The fix is simple enough:  use `IntegerVector` (or equivalently convert your integer data on input).  Below is my altered version of your code.

```
// -*- mode: C++; c-indent-level: 4; c-basic-offset: 4; indent-tabs-mode: nil; -*-

#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH, bigmemory)]]

#include <bigmemory/MatrixAccessor.hpp>
#include <bigmemory/isna.hpp>

using namespace Rcpp;

//Logic for extracting column from a Big Matrix object
template <typename T>
IntegerVector GetColumn_logic(XPtr<BigMatrix> pMat,  MatrixAccessor<T> mat,   int cn) {
    IntegerVector nv(pMat->nrow());
    for(int i = 0; i < pMat->nrow(); i++) {
        if(isna(mat[cn][i])) {
            nv[i] = NA_INTEGER;
        } else {
            nv[i] = mat[cn][i];
        }
    }
    return nv;
}

//' Extract Column from a Big Matrix.
//' 
//' @param pBigMat A bigmemory object address.
//' @param colNum Column Number to extract. Indexing starts from zero.
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector GetColumn(SEXP pBigMat, int colNum) {
    XPtr<BigMatrix> xpMat(pBigMat);

    switch(xpMat->matrix_type()) {
    case 1: return GetColumn_logic(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<char>(*xpMat), colNum);
    case 2: return GetColumn_logic(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<short>(*xpMat), colNum);
    case 4: return GetColumn_logic(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<int>(*xpMat), colNum);
    case 6: return GetColumn_logic(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<float>(*xpMat), colNum);
    case 8: return GetColumn_logic(xpMat, MatrixAccessor<double>(*xpMat), colNum);
    default: throw Rcpp::exception("Unknown type detected for big.matrix object!");
    }
}

/*** R
bm <- bigmemory::as.big.matrix(as.matrix(reshape2::melt(matrix(c(1:4,NA,6:20),4,5))))
bigmemory:::CGetType(bm@address)
bigmemory:::GetCols.bm(bm, 3)
GetColumn(bm@address, 2)
*/
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk, really appreciate all your work on Rcpp. Althought this yields the correct answer, I still think that it would be 'easier' if I could call the GetMatrixCols function - not only because it's designed to do this exact operation, but also because I have a similar needs in other projects -> **The need to call Rcpp Exported functions in my own Rcpp code.** I created a header file containing `SEXP GetMatrixCols(SEXP bigMatAddr, SEXP col);` and built a new version of bigmemory, but when I sourceCpp:ed:  `Error in dyn.load`.. Any ideas how to proceed or am I doing something really stupid?

Comment: Re 1): I think that is you error. Then binary pattern of a NA may not survive the forced copy from `double` to `int`.  Just create `double` on input.  Re 2) and bolded text. No idea what you are talking about. *Every* package using Rcpp Attributes does that, see the Rcpp Atttributes vignette for details.  Re 3) I suspect you are having a hung-up on package build.  New question or post to rcpp-devel?

Comment: Don't know if this is any more clear, but I'll give it a try. There's a cpp function in OtherPackage and it's not defined in the header files of that package. I need to use that function in MyPackage at cpp level. I found a similar question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079811/how-do-i-share-c-functions-in-rcpp-based-libraries-between-r-packages?rq=1). Trying to follow that for the time being. Thank you!

Comment: I see your follow-up question more clearly now.  That is *not* automatic but can be done -- see how my RcppRedis uses RApiSerialize. It is clearly a different question though.  And there is next to nothing Rcpp give you for free here -- this is all R mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing a column of a `big.matrix` in Rcpp is not difficult,
you can for example get an std vector, an Armadillo vector or an Eigen vector
with the following code (there may exist cleaner code):

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen, RcppArmadillo, bigmemory, BH)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <bigmemory/BigMatrix.h>
#include <bigmemory/MatrixAccessor.hpp>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
ListOf<IntegerVector> AccessVector(SEXP pBigMat, int j) {
  XPtr<BigMatrix> xpMat(pBigMat);
  MatrixAccessor<int> macc(*xpMat);

  int n = xpMat->nrow();

  // Bigmemory
  cout << "Bigmemory:"; 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << macc[j][i] << ' ';
  }
  cout << endl;    

  // STD VECTOR
  vector<int> stdvec(macc[j], macc[j] + n); 

  // ARMA VECTOR
  Row<int> armavec(macc[j], n); // Replace Row by Col if you want

  // EIGEN VECTOR
  VectorXi eigenvec(n);
  memcpy(&(eigenvec(0)), macc[j], n * sizeof(int));

  return(List::create(_["Std vector"] = stdvec, 
                      _["Arma vector"] = armavec,
                      _["Eigen vector"] = eigenvec));
}
```

`AccessVector(bm@address, 2)` gets you:

```
Bigmemory:1 2 3 4 -2147483648 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
$`Std vector`
 [1]  1  2  3  4 NA  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

$`Arma vector`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
[1,]    1    2    3    4   NA    6    7    8    9    10    11    12    13    14    15
     [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]    16    17    18    19    20

$`Eigen vector`
 [1]  1  2  3  4 NA  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

You can see that C doesn't know about NAs but when returning to R, you keep them.

So, it depends on what operations you want to do in Rcpp on the columns. I think if you use directly Eigen or Armadillo operations, it should be OK, but you will certainly get lots of NAs in your result.

Maybe it would be clearer if you say what are these operations you want to do.