# how to modify values of a file-backed matrix in bigmemory rcpp

Tags: c++, rcpp, r-bigmemory

I am using R bigmemory package and Rcpp to handle big matrices (1 to 10 Million column x 1000 rows). Once I read an interger matrix consisting in 0, 2 and NA into a filebacked bigmemory matrix in R I would like to modify through C++ all the NA values in order to do imputation of the mean values per column or an arbitrary-value-imputation (I show here the latter).

Below is the Rcpp function I have written and that does not work. My hope was that calling `BigNA(mybigmatrix@address)` from within R could find the elements in the matrix that are NAs and modify its values directly in the backing file.

I think the problem might be in the evaluation of `std::isnan(mat[j][i])`. I checked this by creating an alternative function that counts the NA values with an accumulator and indeed did not count any NA. But once this is solved, I am also not sure if the expression `mat[j][i] = 1` would modify the value in the backing file. Writing those statements feels intuitive for me having an R background but might be wrong.

Any help/suggestion would be very much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <bigmemory/MatrixAccessor.hpp>
#include <numeric>
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH, bigmemory)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(Rcpp)]]


// [[Rcpp::export]]
void BigNA(SEXP pBigMat) {
  /*
  * Imputation of "NA" values for "1" in a big 0, 2 NA matrix.
  */

  // Create the external bigmatrix pointer and iniciate matrix accessor
  XPtr<BigMatrix> xpMat(pBigMat);
  MatrixAccessor<int> mat = (*xpMat);

  // Iterater over the elements in a matrix and when NA is found, substitute for "1"
  for(int i=0; i< xpMat->ncol(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j< xpMat->nrow(); j++){
      if(std::isnan(mat[j][i])){ 
        mat[j][i] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from the difference between `NA` in R and `NAN` in C++.

`MatrixAccessor<int>` gives you an accessor for values of type `int`.  Any number in R can be `NA`, but an `int` in C++ is never `NAN`.  An optimizing compiler could completely ignore `std::isnan(x)` where `x` is of type `int`, as in your case.

To fix this, you could either:

- Use `MatrixAccessor<float>` (or `double`).  This implies actually storing a different data type.
- Check what value you're actually getting for `NA` elements.  I think you will find it is `INT_MIN` in C++ (-2147483648).  Replace `isnan(x)` with `x == INT_MIN`.

Related: [Extracting a column with NA's from a bigmemory object in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569321/extracting-a-column-with-nas-from-a-bigmemory-object-in-rcpp)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is actually the int value at those positions where there are NAs. I will try to implement it like that.

Comment: It works without the use of external headers and even using `MatrixAccessor<int>`. Thus accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Package **bigmemory** has some functions to check NAs.

Just add the header with `#include <bigmemory/isna.hpp>`. 
And replace `std::isnan(mat[j][i])` by `isna(mat[j][i])`.

Comment: I will implement your suggestion and benchmark it with John's suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @MoisésExpósitoAlonso: I'd like to see the results of that benchmark.

Comment: There should be no difference between the two implementations. The only difference is that it has already been implemented by the authors of **bigmemory** (for `char`, `short`, `integer` and `double`). And one should not reinvent the wheel.